# Is there a way to remove this error in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angular JS and I was trying to use routing in it but I am facing some problems.
[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1xvY.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Main

```
<a href="#!london">City 1</a>
<a href="#!paris">City 2</a>

<p>Click on the links.</p>

<p>
  Note that each "view" has its own controller which each gives the "msg"
  variable a value.
</p>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "main.htm",
      })
      .when("/london", {
        templateUrl: "london.htm",
        controller: "londonCtrl",
      })
      .when("/paris", {
        templateUrl: "paris.htm",
        controller: "parisCtrl",
      });
  });
  app.controller("londonCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "I love London";
  });
  app.controller("parisCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "I love Paris";
  });
</script>
```

**london.htm**

```
<h1>London</h1>
```

#### London is the capital city of England.

It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area
  of over 13 million inhabitants.

{{msg}}

**paris.htm**

```
<h1>Paris</h1>
```

#### Paris is the capital city of France.

The Paris area is one of the largest population centers in Europe, with more than 12 million inhabitants.

{{msg}}

Comment: yes, don't make cross origin requests unless they are supported by the other server - however, the error in this case is simpler ... you need to use a http server to serve your page ... `file:///` is not a protocol to use to do any sort of development with ... use `http` at least

Comment: I am doing this on the local server. I am not requesting any file from the server. I am confused.

Comment: no, you are not doing this from a `http` server ... you're loading the page using `file:///` protocol` - the error you posted does not lie about how you are loading the page

Comment: So that means I have to deploy the angular js app

Comment: Can you make fiddle with your code?

Comment: like this - https://jsfiddle.net/4rqyeoxh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors occur because you are not running it under any server or localhost. Angular JS routing will not work if you open the file directly under the browser.

### How to Fix This

Install wamp server or any other server. move your files to servers root directory and run it using its address.

If you use WAMP Server copy your files to a folder and move the folder to C:/Wamp64/www/

In your web browser type : http://localhost/<your_folder>

and for reference i also add the code:

*index.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Sample</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

        <p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>
        
        <a href="#!red">Red</a>
        <a href="#!green">Green</a>
        <a href="#!blue">Blue</a>
        
        <div ng-view></div>
        
        <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
        app.config(function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
          .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "pages/red.html"
          })
          .when("/red", {
            templateUrl : "pages/red.html"
          })
          .when("/green", {
            templateUrl : "pages/green.html"
          })
          .when("/blue", {
            templateUrl : "pages/blue.html"
          });
        });
        </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

*pages/green.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: green;
                color:#ffffff;
            }
        </style>
        <body>
            <h1>Green</h1>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

*pages/red.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: red;
                color:#ffffff;
            }
        </style>
        <body>
            <h1>Red</h1>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

*pages/blue.html*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: blue;
                color:#ffffff;
            }
        </style>
        <body>
            <h1>Blue</h1>
        </body>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: I've been using angular js without any server it works fine. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am using Angular js

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_routing.asp

Comment: usually the the XMLHTTP error is show when you didnot run it on serever.pls wai8 i will send a sample

Comment: i have checked your sample it's working just try running it under a server or a localhost

Comment: Yup, I tried running it on a host and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: I gave you an upvote but my reputation is less than 15 so it's not recorded. Sorry.